# What does the redirection mean in apache beam (python)

Tags: python, apache-beam

In apache beam python sdk , I often see '>>' operator in pipeline procedure.

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pipeline-io

```
lines = p | 'ReadFromText' >> beam.io.ReadFromText('path/to/input-*.csv')
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`>>` is the right bitwise shift operator in Python. The equivalent dunder (double underscore) method is `__rrshift__()`.

The implementation of Apache Beam in Python simply redefines `__rrshift__()` for the `PTransform` class so that names can be added to the transform. It's just special syntax. In your example, "ReadFromText" is the name of the transform.

Reference:
https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/4844af152fface83961dd3f4e89022d1e5bef6d6/sdks/python/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py#L569-L570

Comment: Thanks ! *It's just special syntax. In your example, "ReadFromText" is the name of the transform.* was the answer I have expected.